# Installing PHP7.0 from sid on jessie

Tags: debian, package-management, php, dependencies

I'd like to try PHP7.0 on Debian Jessie and am trying to install it from sid. However, [`php7.0`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php7.0) depends on [`php7.0-common`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php7.0-common) which depends on `php-common > 18` while [`php-common`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php-common) in sid is at 17. Does this mean it's simply impossible to install `php7.0` from this distribution at the moment? Why is that?

I know that it is possible to install from source as explained e.g. [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/), I'm just asking about the official packages.

---

**Note**: the packages in sid have been fixed and it is now (Jan 6, 2016) possible to install from there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have unofficial repos with new versions. Using Debian one of  the best well-known repository for most up-to-date software for web servers for i386 and amd64 packages is dotdeb.

"[**Dotdeb**](https://www.dotdeb.org/about/) is an extra repository providing up-to-date packages for your Debian servers"

They have [**PHP 7**](https://www.dotdeb.org/2015/12/04/php-7-0-0-is-available-for-jessie/) since the 3rd of December (of 2015), and have had a pre-packaged beta since November.

To add the dotdeb repository, from [here](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/).

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

Fetch the repository key and install it.

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
```

Do then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And lastly:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

To search for php 7 related packages:

```
apt-cache search php | grep ^php7
```

In Ubuntu you also already have [**PPAs**](https://bjornjohansen.no/upgrade-to-php7) for it too.

It seems Debian backports do not have yet PHP 7.0. Search [here](http://backports.debian.org/Packages/) in a near future.

Comment: @clarkk They have changed it to php7.0. updated the post. Please in future cases, do not open duplicate questions.

Comment: The debian 7 packages are not always installing properly.
I am running cloud services and installed the debian package for php extensions thousands of times automated.
There is a chance of like 1:50 that the package is partially failing on install and needs a second "dpkg -i".
I could not find the reason so far, I solved it through a loop which installs each extension until it is working.

Comment: Interesting. I had a similar problem with random stalls/hangups in automated installs and had to introduce timeout parameters. They were not limited to a particular repo.

Comment: Yea, I am using a loop in a bash script which tests with "php -r" if the function works and repeats the dpkg install process until it does work.

It happens randomly and on the same linux image, so exactly the same start conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Add the main repository to your sources.list :
Depending on your distribution (Jessie, Wheezy or Squeeze), add these two lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

For PHP 7.0 on Debian 8 “Jessie” (rc3), add these two lines too :

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie-php7.0 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie-php7.0 all
```

Fetch and install the GnuPG key :

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
```

Run `apt-get update  && apt-get install php7-*`

Comment: Failed to fetch http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/jessie-php7.0/all/source/Sources  404  Not Found